# Choice of preference in English

Tags: grammar

There are quite a a lot of situations like this. But here I'll use just two examples.

The first one is with the word *since*. We can say: *There have been a lot of flies since the street sweeper was put out of job*, or *There have been a lot of flies since the putting out of job of the street sweeper*. For the former there is a complete sentence after *since*, but for the latter the part after since is technically a noun phrase. I know both would be okay to use depending on what part of speech is since, but which one is preferred?

Another case is with the word *that* for add-ons. We could say *The thing that we see is falling off is not stationary*. It should be also correct to say *The thing that we see falling off is not stationary*. But which would be the choice of preference?

Comment: "*The thing that we see falling off is not stationary*" is preferred over the other. Also "*There have been a lot of flies since the street sweeper was put out of job*" is more understandable. I don't have any sources to prove this though.

Comment: “The putting out of job of the street sweeper” is not a comprehensible noun phrase. It’s barely grammatical, if at all.

Comment: The phrase "*put out of job*" is incorrect (or at best, very uncommon).  You would more likely say "*put out of* a *job*".  The phrase "the putting out of a job of the street sweeper" may be grammatically correct, but at best it's a huge mouthful that sounds wordy and uneducated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There have been a lot of flies since the street sweeper was put out of a job

This sounds good.

> There have been a lot of flies since the putting out of a job of the street sweeper

This sounds awkward because:

- "Put out" or "put" is not often used in a "noun" sense.  Even though "put out of a job" is a common phrase, "the putting out of a job" sounds weird.  A word like "removal" or "elimination" sounds better.
- Two "of" phrases in a row - *of the job of the street sweeper* - can be jarring - the usual tendency is for a sentence to end after the first *of*.  If you can use possessive case in place of an "of" you probably should - ...*of the street sweeper's job*.

> The thing that we see is falling off is not stationary.

This sounds like you are emphasing "is falling off" - i.e. the fact that it is falling off is unusual or significant and you are pointing this out to someone (i.e. it's happening or visible right now).

> The thing that we see falling off is not stationary.

This sounds OK.  If you are not emphasizing a currently happening or specific event of "is falling off", this sounds better.